# React: How to create a scrollable container for dynamic SVG?

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to create a react component that renders a dynamic SVG. I don't know in advance how many elements it will contain, and the containing `<div>` is sized by a flexbox, so I don't know those dimensions in advance either.

What I would like to do is: if the SVG content exceeds the visible bounds, a scrollbar on the container should allow the user to move the SVG viewport to see each part of it.

Here's a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/ezqhu4po/1/

[image]

The task is to dynamically add a scrollbar to the `svg-wrapper` `<div>` that allows the user to scroll from the first circle to the last circle, no matter how many circles they add (using the button). Some rules:

- Setting fixed sizes to any of the `div`s is not a solution here.
- Also, since in the final solution I need to draw not just circles, the content of the SVG need to be considered to be arbitrary (arithmetics on circle position and radius to compute a fixed size upfront is not a helpful solution).
- Resizing the div at runtime (e.g. by resizing the browser window) needs to be considered as well.

Can this even be done? Every solution I could find used hardcoded pixel sizes somewhere.